# Is is any command that open shared folders in Windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows

For example when we want to open Microsoft Paint we can open run ( windows + R ) and then write 'mspaint' and then enter 
so is there any sshortcut command allow me open my shared folders ? 
I know that 'mspaint' is just the name of the file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\mspaint.exe' but i think may be a shortcut command for shared folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (WinKey + R) and then type in `\\your_computer_name`

Answer (score 1):

Which shared folders? If you want the MMC plugin for Shared Folders, which lists all shares on your computer and users currently accessing them, the command is `fsmgmt.msc`. If you want to access all (non-hidden) shares on your computer, you can type `\\%computername%\` into the run box.

Comment: it's my first time to know this tool "Shared Folders" fsmgmt.msc
Thanks nhinkle